# React and TypeScript, how to properly define direct properties of my component class?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I've just started working with TypeScript and I ran into an error. Often I initialize refs in my constructor but TypeScript doesn't like it, consider this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent<types.MyComponentProps>
  constructor(props: MyComponentProps){
    super(props);

    // error here: Property 'target' does not exist on type 'MyComponent'
    this.target = React.createRef(); 
  }
}
```

I know that `React.PureComponent` accepts an argument for props and an argument for state but how can I let `TypeScript` know that my component should expect properties directly, such as refs? Or alternatively, is this an anti-pattern and should I be defining refs differently?

Comment: I'm not a React expert but it seems you'd just need to declare `target` as a property of the class. Like `private target: Whatever-Type-React.createRef-Returns`above the constructor

Comment: oh wow that seems so obvious but I just couldn't wrap my head around it, thank you

Comment: If you want the type information (and functions that may come along with that, for instance: scrollTo for a ScrollView component) for the component you are adding a ref to, I would recommend taking a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize `target` as a class property:

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent<types.MyComponentProps>
  target = React.createRef(); 

  constructor(props: MyComponentProps){
    super(props);
    // May not need a constructor at all
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I do it, this way you get all the necessary type information for your ref. For example: a ScrollView

```
interface Props {}

interface State {}

class SomeComponent extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {

  private target: React.RefObject<ScrollView>; // or some other type of Component

  constructor(props: Props){
    super(props);

    this.target = React.createRef(); 
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <ScrollView ref={this.target}>
        ...
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }

  // now you can define a scrollToTop method for instance
  private scrollToTop = (): void => {
    // The scrollTo method is available from autocomplete since it was defined as a ScrollView ref
    this.scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: 0, animated});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring target in the constructor which is wrong, do it like this

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent<types.MyComponentProps>
  constructor(props: MyComponentProps){
    super(props);

  }
this.target = React.createRef();
}
```